# How to change growl position

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How can I change p:growl position and width.

The growl should popup at the center bottom of the screen.

```
.ui-growl {
position:fixed;
bottom: 30% !important;
left: 37%;
width: 500px;
z-index:9999;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle for it? or include your HTML here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `left: 50%;` and add `margin-left: -250px;`.

Alternatively, you could use CSS `calc` (see [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc)):

`left: calc(50% - 250px);`